# ASP Classic filter for "onmouseover" keyword xss

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, xss

It's a redundent question on the Internet, but yet, no simple answer. I know I won't get rid of all XSS simply by filtering, but I'd like to start with it. I am currently working on ASP Classic project with server code written in JScript (not the usual VBScript). We found that we were vulnerable to some XSS attack. One is pretty tough to get rid of, since I am not a javascript master. When you use a URL like the one below, the attack is succesfull.

> [http://mysite/default.asp?NumVol=%20onmouseover=%22alert%28document.cookie%29%22%20style=%22font-size:999999999999px;%22%20href=](http://www.google.com)

I tried the HTMLEncode, the replace method on the NumVol parameter string... But it still displays the cookie. All I'm looking for is a small replace method, a regex or whatever simple thing to manage that particular case.

This is an old production app and they don't want to spend much time on it. Just some security basics. We are definitely not instaling a library that rely on .NET (like OWASP) to fix this for now, because we will rebuild the app in .NET soon.

**EDIT**

Here is a sample code that I tried. You can see that I use HTMLEncole plus some filters with a "replace". The "%" char is there, but it doesn't work, since the onmouseover is written. What I need is a syntax exemple (regex or someting) in Javacript that I can apply in that case.

```
var sPage = "" + Request.ServerVariables ( "SCRIPT_NAME" );
var NumVol = Request.QueryString("NumVol");
var comp = Request.QueryString("comp")
var nav = Request.QueryString("nav");
var NoEle = Request.QueryString("NoEle");
var NoCons = Request.QueryString("NoCons");

if (Lg=="en")  {
    var pageSourceValid = Server.HTMLEncode(sPage + "?Lg=fr");
    Response.Write("<a href=");
        if ((NumVol+"" != "undefined") && (NumVol+"" != "")) {
            pageSourceValid += "&NumVol=" + NumVol.replace(/\<|\>|\"|\'|\%|\;|\(|\)|\&|\+|\-/g,"");
        }
        if ((nav+"" != "undefined") && (nav+"" != "")) {
            pageSourceValid += "&nav=" + nav.replace(/\<|\>|\"|\'|\%|\;|\(|\)|\&|\+|\-/g,"") + "";
        }
        if ((comp+"" != "undefined") && (comp+"" != "")) {
            pageSourceValid += "&comp=" + comp.replace(/\<|\>|\"|\'|\%|\;|\(|\)|\&|\+|\-/g,"") + "";
        }
        if ((NoEle+"" != "undefined") && (NoEle+"" != "")) {
            pageSourceValid += "&NoEle=" + NoEle.replace(/\<|\>|\"|\'|\%|\;|\(|\)|\&|\+|\-/g,"") + "";
        }
        if ((NoCons+"" != "undefined") && (NoCons+"" != "")) {
            pageSourceValid += "&NoCons=" + NoCons.replace(/\<|\>|\"|\'|\%|\;|\(|\)|\&|\+|\-/g,"") + "";
        }

Response.Write(Server.HTMLEncode(pageSourceValid));
Response.Write (" class=lienBanniere>");
Response.Write ("Français");
Response.Write ("</a>");
```

}

Comment: You don't show how your displaying it on the page. Show a snippet of the ASP JScript that is causing the issue would help. Like the part where you're trying HTMLEncode and the surrounding lines.

Comment: I think you should use Http referer. If it is Jscript, then I don't know the syntax but if it is a sever side scripting language then there should be a http referer checking function or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use html attribute escaping and html escaping when you output the value.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet